# Windows Forms Threads are losing their culture

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

We have a .net 3.5 multi-threaded windows forms application. Is is launching 4-5 background workers/ async calls to retrieve data. About 1 in 10 times, one of the threads throws the following error. Sometimes the error is a null exception instead but the same exact call stack. We have tracked the issue down to the thread somehow losing its CultureInfo. Anyone else ran into this?

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(Int32 cultureId, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureByLCIDOrName(Int32 preferLCID, String fallbackToString)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InitUserDefaultUICulture()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_UserDefaultUICulture()
   at System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentUICulture()
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Environment.ResourceHelper.GetResourceStringCode(Object userDataIn)
   at System.Environment.GetResourceFromDefault(String key)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Init(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.GetWriterForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Serialize(SoapClientMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Comment: Show us your code.  Any hope of a meaningful answer here is lost without seeing the code.

Comment: in 4.0 CultureInfo became Thread static...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Looks like you are having a problem with a Managed Debugging Assistant, the StreamWriterBufferedDataLost MDA.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com, important to include a small repro project.  This should not be a problem when you don't use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with default culture for entire domain using [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and/or [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and see if that helps. All in all, you'll be able to ensure whether it's related to thread's culture

**UPD**: that specific exception may be thrown when using sync methods like `lock`, `Monitor`, etc on **value types**, calls to sync methods **will box value, creating new one every time**. I doubt it could be such serios bug in framework.

Can you check your synchronization code?

**UPD2**: ok, let's try to ***debug***.

- First off, turn on [break on every exception thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- Next, enable [.NET Framework debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) that will help you to
  **locate an error**

After that, there is a high chance for a workaround/solution for you problem

Comment: That appears to be .net 4.5 only?

Comment: unfortunately yes, on lower versions you should set thread culture for every thread individually

Comment: @Kenoyer130 updated my answer with some thoughts on exception type

Answer (score 1):

From just looking at the call stack, this appears to be a framework bug (of sorts).  It seems that the StreamWriter constructor is performing a non-thread-safe operation (accessing GetCultureTableRecord) through a complex series of calls.  My recommendation would be to serialize your calls to the StreamWriter constructor:

```
// Put this somewhere convenient
public static Object swConstructorLock = new Object();
```

then, when you create your StreamWriters:

```
// Lock this constructor because it does something that isnt thread-safe as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113366/windows-forms-threads-are-losing-their-culture
StreamWriter myStreamWriter;
lock (swConstructorLock) {
    myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(theStreamToWrite);
}
```

Comment: Note that SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke is creating the StreamWriter. The application code is not :/

Comment: Ah- I didn't see that.  Looks like you'd need to switch to async calls then (which you really ought to be doing anyway, rather than explicit threading).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.begininvoke.aspx

Comment: Funny that is exactly what I am doing. Legacy code and all that :P

Answer (score 1):

I found that CultureInfo.ClearCachedData was being called on every web request :/ Removing that fixed the issue. There seems that Culture still needs some sort of lock since thread A calls ClearCachedData and thread B requests the data and it throws a null exception.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception (once, out of a blue), also in a .NET 3.5 app:

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(Int32 cultureId, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureByLCIDOrName(Int32 preferLCID, String fallbackToString)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InitUserDefaultCulture()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_UserDefaultCulture()
   at System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentCulture()
   at System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.get_CurrentInfo()
   at System.DateTime.ToString(String format)
```

This happened in a locked section, but the lock was not a value type.